# How can I get browser to prompt to save password using gwt bootstrap?

Tags: gwt, twitter-bootstrap, uibinder, gwt-bootstrap

I have a login page containing a gwt bootstrap text box ,password text box and submit button

```xml
<g:VerticalPanel height="400px" width="50%">
                <b:WellForm  height="400px" ui:field="loginPanel">


                    <g:VerticalPanel horizontalAlignment="ALIGN_CENTER"
                        width="100%">
                        <b:FormLabel ui:field="emailErrorLabel" visible="false">
                            <font color="red">
                                <i>&nbsp;Please enter your login name</i>
                            </font>
                        </b:FormLabel>
                        <b:TextBox  alternateSize="LARGE" b:id="Email"
                            ui:field="Email" placeholder="E-mail"  width="335px"
                            height="30px" />
                    </g:VerticalPanel>


                    <g:VerticalPanel horizontalAlignment="ALIGN_CENTER" width="100%">
                        <b:FormLabel ui:field="passwordErrorLabel" visible="false">
                            <font color="red">
                                <i>&nbsp; Please enter password</i>
                            </font>
                        </b:FormLabel>
                        <b:PasswordTextBox  width="335px"
                            alternateSize="LARGE" ui:field="password" placeholder="Password"
                            height="30px" />
                    </g:VerticalPanel>
                    <b:Button type="PRIMARY" ui:field="loginButton" icon="SIGNIN">Login</b:Button></b:Wellform>
```

im setting following properties

```java
loginPanel.setMethod("POST");
    loginPanel.getElement().setPropertyString("autocomplete", "on");
    Email.getElement().setAttribute("type", "text");
    password.getElement().setAttribute("type", "password");
```

and on click of login i'm calling an rpc which does the loggin in . What property am i missing .how can i get the browser to prompt save password option.

Answer (score 1):

In order for a browser to detect a save-able password, you must have the following HTML:

```xml
<form>
    <input type="text" />
    <input type="password" />
</form>
```

Make sure your GWT code compiles into those elements in the browser. **When that form does the "submit" action, the browser will ask to save the password**. I think since you have a clickhandler to log in the user manually, instead of your form performing a `POST`, the browser doesn't realize it is a login.

Also, I believe you don't need this:

```java
password.getElement().setAttribute("type", "password");
```

because `<b:PasswordTextBox` already compiles into `<input type="password" />`. It is probably also unnecessary for the "Email" field, but I'm not sure.